# how to make DIY seed tape?

Tags: seeds

I want to plant basic things like carrots, radishes, lettuce, and many more. People have been buying there seeds but in a seed tape form. How could I make my own here at home? What is to not be used for while doing something like this?

Comment: More work than just planting them, IMHO. Not a process that scales well to small-scale. Pelleting is probably more "home production friendly" if you don't want to deal with handling small seed directly.

Comment: I don't even bother. For lettuce I loosen the top of the soil and toss the seeds in. If there are too many seeds together, I move them about with my finger. It works fine. Lettuce cares more about soil quality than spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly abbreviated version of advice (with pictures) at [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Your-Own-Seed-Tapes/):

> **Step 1: Materials**
>
> •  Any kind of Seeds
>   •  Zip lock Baggies or plastic containers - each one marked for what type of seed tape it is in it
>   •  1 Tbl Corn Starch
>   •  1 C Cold Water
>   •  Paper Towels, cut in 1 1/2 - 2 inch Strips and folded in half
>   •  Any squeeze type bottle, (you can wash and use an empty mustard or ketchup bottle)
>   • A drop of food coloring (optional)
>
> **Step 2: Prepare Your 'Seed Glue'**    Dissolve Cornstarch in Water over a medium heat until it boils and thickens. Mixture should look
>   opaque and cling slightly to a fork before dripping off.
>
> Let it cool and transfer into squeeze bottle add 1 drop of food
>   coloring and shake the bottle to make your 'Glue Dots' easier to see.
>
> **Step 3: Prepare Your 'Seed Tape'**
>
> Lay out Paper Towel Strips, and place dots across one side of the fold
>   with the cornstarch mixture spacing the dots according to the planting
>   directions of the Seed Packets.
>
> I am using Blanket Flower Seeds for this project.
>
> **Step 4: Add Your Seeds**
>
> Place seeds on top of the dots, fold other half of paper towel on top
>   and let it dry completely.
>
> Store in a plastic bag or container until you are ready to plant. (I
>   like to keep mine in the bottom drawer of the fridge).
>
> Drop the seed packet with instructions in with your seed tapes for
>   future reference.

And an alternative but very similar description (using toilet rather than kitchen paper) at: [diy network](http://www.diynetwork.com/how-to/make-and-decorate/crafts/make-toilet-paper-seed-tape).

To be avoided are glue that does not dissolve in water and paper that does not fall apart easily (is not tissue) or is high in [chlorine](http://www.rollandinc.com/en/blog/problem-chlorine-paper) - see [ChasingGreen.org](http://www.chasinggreen.org/article/5-earth-safe-toilet-paper-brands/).

Seed tape might be a way to shift a little time required for gardening from a busy season to a quiet one.